# Google Spreadsheet not accessible from miso dataset or tabletop

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-sheets, tabletop.js, miso.dataset

I recently asked this question about why my google spreadsheet data wasnt being called, even though the example one worked

[Using Google Spreadsheet as JSON file using tabletop to datatables returns error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24150667/using-google-spreadsheet-as-json-file-using-tabletop-to-datatables-returns-error)

I tried a completely different library as I thought it was a problem with tabletop.js... I tried this example using Miso dataset...

http://misoproject.com/dataset/tutorials/googlespreadsheets

I got the example working perfectly but as soon as I switch in my spreadsheet key it stops working! What is wrong with my spreadsheet? It is public and published, I can't understand it

Anyone had any success with calling a google spreadsheet recently?

Here is the damned spreadsheet.. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/15d4wQR69upqZbnZyArSsxKXpT8R9w8_9dmrabzugAks/edit#gid=0

All ideas appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 0):

It likely has to do with the "new google spreadsheets". Note the different URL structure in the original and new sheet.